# Align object position to grid

Tags: c++, math

I want to align an object position to grid.
For instance, if my object position is (102, 93) and
my grid size is 10 the aligned position (multiple) must be (100, 90).
My program does it a lot of times.

Currently i'm using this:

```
inline int Align(int value, int size)
{
    return (value - (value % size));
}
```

Then, i do this when the object position is changed:

```
this->m_x = Align(new_x, GRID_SIZE);
this->m_y = Align(new_y, GRID_SIZE);
```

My questions are:
Is this a good way to align a object to grid?

The % operator is fast (i use it a lot)?

If i use float intead of int what i can do to align the position?

Comment: Why would you even consider using float - assuming you are aligning to pixels - since you cannot have a fraction of a pixel

Comment: @AdrianCornish I will consider it. But i have to align to 5*n values (n > 2).

Comment: So - you still cannot align to half a pixel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing the same thing using integer math is like this:

```
inline int Align(int value, int size)
{
    return (value/size)*size;
}
```

If your size is a power of 2, you can use bitmasking (e.g. for size 16):

```
inline int AlignTo16(int value)
{
    return value & 0xfff0
}
```

Comment: Note that this will always round down, not to the nearest (i.e. 99 will be rounded to 90, not 100). A modified version would add `size/2` before the division to get better rounding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [std::fmod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod):

```
inline float Align(float value, float size)
{
    // Added std::abs to give correct behaviour for negative values
    return value - std::abs(std::fmod(value, size));
}
```

or alternatively:

```
inline float Align(float value, float size)
{
    return std::floor(value/size) * size;
}
```